# I would like to get the value of a given token with in a string

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am currently working on a project that will allow me to bring in a string that would have a designated token that I will grab, get the designated value and remove the token and push to an array.  I have the following condition which I am using split in JavaScript but it is not splitting on the designated ending token.

**This is the beginning string**

```
"~~/Document Heading 1~~<div>This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>~~end~~<div class="/Document Heading 1">This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>"
```

**Current Code Block**

```
 var segmentedStyles = [];
 var contentToInsert = selectedContent.toString();
 var indexValue = selectedContent.toString().search("~~");

 if (indexValue <= 0) {                            
                        var insertionStyle = contentToInsert.split("~~");
                        segmentedStyles.push(insertionStyle);                                                             
                    }
```

The designated token is enclosed by a "~~ .... ~~".  In this code Block it is going through the condition but the string it is not splitting correctly. I am currently getting the Following string pushed to my array.

**This is my current result**

```
[,/Document Heading 1<div>This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>end,

<div class="/Document Heading 1">This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>]
```

**My Goal**

I would like to split a string that is coming in if a token is present.  For example I would like to split a string starting from ~~.....~~ through ~~end~~.  The array should hold two values like the following

```
   segmentedStyles = [<div>This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>],[<div class="/Document Heading 1">This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>]
```

Comment: please add the string, you like to split and the result after splitting and rearranging

Comment: This is what I am bringing in =  "This is the beginning string "

This is my current result = `[,/Document Heading 1<div>This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>end,

<div class="/Document Heading 1">This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>]`

Comment: is the first `~~` always followed by a `/`?

Comment: no it can be followed by anything, I am using the ~~ ...~~ simply as a container to hold a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for matching the parts.

```js
var string = '~~/Document Heading 1~~<div>This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>~~end~~<div class="/Document Heading 1">This is a test &lt;b&gt;JUDO&lt;/b&gt; TKD</div>',
array = string.split('~~').filter(function (_, i) { 
    return i && !(i % 2); // just get element 2 and 4 or all other even indices
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yup that will work the only thing is that I am not guaranteed that what will follow will be a <div> I should be expecting anything.  Would you think a conversion to a char array make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string always starts with `~~/` you could use the following regex to get the array you want

`~~([^\/].*)~~end~~(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/hJ0vM4/1

Comment: Your regex expression is invalid Carl, it will will not hit the end delimeter

Answer (score 0):

I honestly didn't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish haha, but I sort of understood what you're trying to do :)

First, just trying to make it clear some stuff. If you `split()` your string using `/~~/` as the Regular Expression for splitting you'll get all the bits surrounded by "~~" in an array, like you did.

Second, if you change the tokens to `~~START~~` and `~~END~~` (tokens that never change) you can accomplish what you want by simply doing `string.split(/~~(START|END)~~/)` - Much shorter and quicker ;)

Third is the string always in the format `~~<something>~~THE STUFF YOU WANT~~end~~MORE STUFF YOU WANT`? If it is, I'd suggest doing this:

```
function splitTheTokens(str) {
    var result = [];
    var parts = str.split(/~~end~~/);

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (!parts[i]) { continue; } // Skips blanks
        if (parts[i].indexOf("~~") == 0) {
            // In case you want to do something with the name thing:
            var thisPartName = parts[i].substring(2, parts[i].indexOf("~~", 2));

            // What (I think) you actually want
            var thisPartValue = parts[i].substring(thisPartName.length + 4);

            result.push(thisPartValue);
        }
        else {
            result.push(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps :D